# Add page numbering in each page footer using SelectPDF.Net when PdfTextElement is not an option?

Tags: c#, pdf, page-numbering, selectpdf

I'm using SelectPDF for .NET to convert a HTML document into PDF.

I'm required to add page numbering on each page footer following this format:

```
"Page {page_number} of {total_pages}";
```

That said, PDF is created flawlessly. So, I try to use instructions from the following link, and then no `PdfTextElement` available in the library!?

[SelectPdf for .NET - Page Numbering - C# / ASP.NET Sample](https://selectpdf.com/demo/page-numbering.aspx)

Here code from the link in case the link dies someday.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using SelectPdf;

namespace SelectPdf.Samples
{
    public partial class page_numbering : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void BtnCreatePdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // create a new pdf document
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
            doc.Margins = new PdfMargins(10, 10, 0, 0);

            // create a new pdf font
            PdfFont font = doc.AddFont(PdfStandardFont.Helvetica);
            font.Size = 24;

            // add a new page to the document
            PdfPage page = doc.AddPage();

            // footer template (100 points in height) with text element
            doc.Footer = doc.AddTemplate(doc.Pages[0].ClientRectangle.Width, 100);
            PdfTextElement text1 = new PdfTextElement(0, 50, 
                "Page: {page_number} of {total_pages}.", font);
            text1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            doc.Footer.Add(text1);

            // create a new text element and add it to the page
            // if page elements are added after header and footer is set, 
            // they will not be displayed in those areas.
            PdfTextElement text = new PdfTextElement(0, 0, Helper.SomeLongText(), font);
            page.Add(text);

            // save pdf document
            doc.Save(Response, false, "Sample.pdf");

            // close pdf document
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

If the real code could work the way this sample code does, it would be awesome! But then again, I found no `PdfTextElement`. I can only find `PdfTextSection`.

Currently using SelectPdf 18.4.0.0.

[SelectPDF v18.4.0.0 Download](https://selectpdf.com/downloads/)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was not using the complete [SelectPDF](https://selectpdf.com/downloads/) library, but only its lightweight SelectHtmlToPdf.

The PdfTextElement object ain't available for Select.HtmlToPdf. It is only in the Select.Pdf library.